# Unable to ping or ssh into embedded Linux device: eno1 has no IPv4 address

Tags: ssh, embedded, ping, ipv4

I am trying to `ssh` into an embedded Linux device (let's call it `petalinux`) connected to my Ubuntu server running `22.04` (let's call it `oip`). `petalinux` and `oip` are connected by a direct ethernet cable and a serial UART. I am able to connect to the device using a serial terminal (`minicom`), but `ssh` times out. I am also unable to `ping` the device. So, I believe it is one of two things:

- Network settings are incompatible (subnet mask, gateway, etc.), or
- The firewall on the embedded Linux device is not letting traffic through.

In order to check the first one, I tried finding the IP address of `oip`; however, I do not see an IPv4 associated with `eno1`:

**EDIT (add output of ifconfig, arp, netstat, and ip route)**

```
$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether cc:48:3a:66:a3:b3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp0s31f6
    inet6 fe80::91fe:23e9:430c:4c90/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:5d:96:04 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: wlp60s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 18:47:3d:31:82:dd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.29.146/24 brd 192.168.29.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp60s0
       valid_lft 40510sec preferred_lft 40510sec
    inet6 2405:201:d001:8b9b:6aa1:628a:c18a:852c/64 scope global temporary dynamic
       valid_lft 4186sec preferred_lft 4186sec
    inet6 2405:201:d001:8b9b:9fbf:f0f:d3d4:34f5/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
       valid_lft 4186sec preferred_lft 4186sec
    inet6 fe80::8d6c:7a7c:f242:2c67/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:0c:f4:0a:c5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: br-71e276fedf6f: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:93:94:0b:70 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.19.0.1/16 brd 172.19.255.255 scope global br-71e276fedf6f
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

$ ifconfig -a
br-71e276fedf6f: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.19.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.19.255.255
        ether 02:42:93:94:0b:70  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:0c:f4:0a:c5  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether cc:48:3a:66:a3:b3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 12827  bytes 1018633 (1.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3854  bytes 679852 (679.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  memory 0xed700000-ed720000

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 31692  bytes 4654677 (4.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 31692  bytes 4654677 (4.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:5d:96:04  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp60s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.29.146  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.29.255
        inet6 fe80::8d6c:7a7c:f242:2c67  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2405:201:d001:8b9b:9fbf:f0f:d3d4:34f5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2405:201:d001:8b9b:2e48:2aca:eaf7:f31b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 18:47:3d:31:82:dd  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 7661151  bytes 11185482986 (11.1 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2146363  bytes 514484076 (514.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

$ arp -an
? (192.168.29.73) at 5c:e9:1e:9c:3a:b0 [ether] on wlp60s0
? (192.168.29.1) at a8:da:0c:c0:06:48 [ether] on wlp60s0

$ netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.29.1    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlp60s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 virbr0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 docker0
172.19.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 br-71e276fedf6f
192.168.29.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlp60s0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 virbr0

$ ip route
default via 192.168.29.1 dev wlp60s0 proto dhcp metric 600
169.254.0.0/16 dev virbr0 scope link metric 1000 linkdown
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
172.19.0.0/16 dev br-71e276fedf6f proto kernel scope link src 172.19.0.1 linkdown
192.168.29.0/24 dev wlp60s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.29.146 metric 600
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown
```

On `oip`'s side, the `ip addr` is more straightforward. Here, I have set the `eth0` IP statically.
**EDIT (add output of ifconfig, arp, netstat, and ip route)**

```
$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: sit0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
3: can0: <NOARP,ECHO> mtu 16 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 10
    link/can
4: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a6:e6:68:9d:46:5f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.10/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a4e6:68ff:fe9d:465f/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

$ ifconfig -a
can0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          NOARP  MTU:16  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:10
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:47

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr A6:E6:68:9D:46:5F
          inet addr:192.168.0.10  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a4e6:68ff:fe9d:465f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:77 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:692 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:17852 (17.4 KiB)  TX bytes:54248 (52.9 KiB)
          Interrupt:48

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:626 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:626 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:56300 (54.9 KiB)  TX bytes:56300 (54.9 KiB)

sit0      Link encap:IPv6-in-IPv4
          NOARP  MTU:1480  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

$ arp -an
-sh: arp: command not found

$ netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0

$ ip route
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 proto static
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.10
```

In addition, the SSH server *is* running on the device, as checked via the `sudo systemctl status sshd` command. The end-goal is to debug why I am unable to `ping` or `ssh` to the device.

Comment: Show us the tutorial / blog / documentation URL you relied on when setting this up. Were you hoping the ubuntu server would respond to a DHCP broadcast request from the embedded device? (Also, please tell us what the two hostnames are, so we can conveniently refer to them.) The two hosts have to agree on routing details, so `ifconfig -a`, `arp -an`, and `netstat -rn` are all relevant. It sounds like server does not have a useful link IP address, nor does the embedded device. You can `ping` from either direction, and observe with `tcpdump` (wireshark) on the other host.

Comment: Do you have a route set up so you can access the 192.168.0.0/24 network from your 192.168.29.0/24 host? What does `ip route` return?

Comment: The `fe80::/64` address on your `eno1` is a link-scope address usable only for things like DHCP; since you don't have a real v6 addr _or_ any v4 addr almost certainly that interface/link isn't actually connected. Your `wlp60s0` is connected to something, but what? Is it in the same collision domain (i.e. link-set)? It's certainly not the same subnet, as @doneal24 notes.

Comment: @J_H and @doneal24, I have edited the question to add the output of the relevant commands. Have also named the two systems: `oip` is the Ubuntu server, and `petalinux` is the embedded device. Also, to be clear, `oip` and `petalinux` are connected directly by an ethernet cable and a serial UART (have edited this into the question as well).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, `wlp60s0` is connected to my PC, which I am using to remote into the server. Overall, it is PC -> server (`oip`) -> embedded device (`petalinux`). Between `oip` and `petalinux`, there is only a direct ethernet connection.

Comment: "_oip and petalinux are connected directly by an ethernet cable_" Tell us both interface names, please. It is not yet clear that this cable is functioning. In some contexts one needs a [crossover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable) cable for a host-to-host connection, while in others, one or more NICs will re-assign Tx / Rx during autoneg. For now, recommend you replace the single cable with a pair of cables connected to a switch (a layer-2 bridge). In order we must see both interfaces get proper IP addr, with proper route, and MAC addr of peer in ARP table, and good ping.

Comment: @J_H, could you help me understand what you mean by interface names here? Beyond the interfaces show in the output of `ip addr` and `ifconfig`, I am not understanding what this could mean.

Comment: I'm trying to focus on individual lines of `ifconfig` output and of the route table. For example "we expect oip to connect to that cable via interface foo0 with IP4 address 10.9.8.2/24" and "we expect petalinux to connect to that cable via interface baz0 as 10.9.8.3/24". Or specify IPv6. I want to know the IPv{4,6} name + mask of that cable, and the addresses the two hosts should be using, and then figure out if we have evidence that one or both of them _are_ configured to use that. As it stands, maybe one or maybe both is broken and I've not yet isolated which to focus on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With 192.168.0.10/24 already set on *petalinux*'s *eth0* linked to *oip*'s *eno1*, to allow communication between oip and petalinux, run this on *oip* (as *root* user, meaning it probably should be prepended by `sudo` ):

```
ip addr add 192.168.0.11/24 dev eno1
```

And that's it: each should now be able to reach the other using the other's IP address: 192.168.0.10 or 192.168.0.11 (both being within 192.168.0.0/24). I don't see any strange problem here, except the superfluous information (libvirt and Docker are running too).

Note: *petalinux* won't be reachable directly from the PC (mentioned in [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/759654/unable-to-ping-or-ssh-into-embedded-linux-device-eno1-has-no-ipv4-address/759760#comment1448055_759654)) nor can it reach "outside" through *oip* for at least two reasons: Ubuntu's Docker sets filter/FORWARD to DROP, and the PC probably doesn't have an adequate route to 192.168.0.0/24. But that's not part of the question.